# Convert times into interval array

Tags: php

If I have the following variables:

```
$starttime = '09:00';  // Start time
$endtime = '21:00';  // End time
$interval = '30';  // In minutes
```

What would be the best way to generate the following array?

```
[
    "09:00" => "09:30",
    "09:30" => "10:00",
    "10:00" => "10:30",
    "10:30" => "11:00",
     ...
    "20:00" => "20:30",
    "20:30" => "21:00"
]
```

There are some similar topics that show how to array time intervals but none of them have been able to show my specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using DateTime class with DateInterval you can achieve what you need.

DateTime - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php

DateInterval - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php

```
<?php
$startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "09:00");
$endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "22:00");
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("30 minutes");

$result = [];
while ($startTime <= $endTime) {
  $result[$startTime->format('H:i')] = $startTime->add($interval)->format('H:i');
}

echo print_r($result, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone, same approach as your \o/

Comment: yours is shorter though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add 30 min to by this command :

```php
    $time=date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $time));
```

For your problem can set a **`while`** loop(for check condition).

Then set and array and set index to :

```php
     date("H:i", strtotime('+'.$interval.' minutes', $time));`
```

And set value to :

```php
     date("H:i", strtotime('+'.(2*$interval).'minutes', $time));
```

Then update **`$time`**.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use a 'while' loop to increment a timestamp until $endtime is reached.  Here's a working example:

```
$starttime = '09:00';  // Start time
$endtime = '21:00';  // End time
$interval = '30';  // In minutes

$result = [];
$last = strtotime($starttime);
$endtimestamp = strtotime($endtime);

while ($last < $endtimestamp) {

    $next = strtotime("+{$interval} minutes", $last);
    $result[date('H:i', $last)] = date('H:i', $next);
    $last = $next;

}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// define start/end
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '09:00');
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '21:00');

// define the interval
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$interval->invert = 1;

// get date range
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

// loop and build your array
$range = [];
foreach ($daterange as $date){
    $range[$date->format("H:i")] = $date->sub($interval)->format("H:i");
}

print_r($range);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [09:00] => 09:30
    [09:30] => 10:00
    [10:00] => 10:30
    [10:30] => 11:00
    [11:00] => 11:30
    [11:30] => 12:00
    [12:00] => 12:30
    [12:30] => 13:00
    [13:00] => 13:30
    [13:30] => 14:00
    [14:00] => 14:30
    [14:30] => 15:00
    [15:00] => 15:30
    [15:30] => 16:00
    [16:00] => 16:30
    [16:30] => 17:00
    [17:00] => 17:30
    [17:30] => 18:00
    [18:00] => 18:30
    [18:30] => 19:00
    [19:00] => 19:30
    [19:30] => 20:00
    [20:00] => 20:30
    [20:30] => 21:00
)
```

https://3v4l.org/FqViY